# "I forgot my pin" on windows 10 does not work

Tags: windows-10, login, password-recovery, pin

I forgot my PIN on my Windows 10 VirtualBox machine. I don't see any other way to make logon and I just see the form to type the PIN. There is also the "I forgot my PIN" to click but it doesn't work. I mean it shows me an empty form to insert the password. [image: This is the screenshot.]
Anyone know how can I solve, I know my password.

Comment: Since you're logging in through the MS account, are you certain the VM has internet connectivity?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - That screenshot indicates the VM does not.  It appears that if the account were logged in, it would be prompting to verify the Microsoft Account, I recognize the behavior from my own VMs.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik yes, it has connectivity because it has downloaded the updates few hours ago.